# How can I replicate focalmean with focal statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, focal-statistics

I am trying to get rid of some small gaps of no data in my rasters. I would previously have used focalmean but it is no longer available. I've tried what I expected to work but I'm getting errors.

What I have is:

```
MYNEWRAST = Con(IsNull("rasterrast"),FocalStatistics("rasterrast",NbrRectangle(50,50),"MEAN","NODATA"),"rasterrast")
```

and this is giving me a pretty unhelpful error message:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5142, in FocalStatistics     ignore_nodata)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper     result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5136, in Wrapper     ignore_nodata)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 498, in <lambda>     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. General function failure [FocalSt_rast6] Failed to execute (FocalStatistics).
```

Has anyone had something similar working, and did they do it differently?

[image]

Comment: Try this:Con(IsNull("rasterrast "), FocalStatistics("rasterrast ", NbrRectangle(50, 50, "CELL"), "MEAN"), " rasterrast ")

Comment: I've tried it, and no luck there

Comment: It works for me. Can you add a screen of the raster calculator window?

Comment: @AlbertC its in the question now.

Comment: Yes, well...I asked you to post a screen because I wanted to see what output you were trying to create but it is cut, and I can't see it, hehe. I think the problem may be there.

Comment: Ah sorry its going into my default gdb as rastercalc1

Comment: Well, then I don't know...I'd first check if the spatial analyst license is available, and if it is I'd do some "just in case" actions: make sure your raster is projected, change the size of the focal 10, 10 insted of 50, 50. (Actually it is more accurate to do 5 times 10, 10 than once 50, 50), Change your output directory, do it outside the raster calculator (run the focal statistics and the conditional tools separately from the toolbox)...

Comment: It seems that you were on the right track - saving outside a fgdb seems to work